# No network controller found - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, wireless, bluetooth, adapter

When booting my Laptop today I noticed my bluetooth and wifi was not working. Both state in the settings that no adapter is found. I started searching for solutions but nothing worked so far, and I've got the impression that at least the wireless network controller should be found. When I do `lspci |grep Network` nothing gets displayed.

When only using `lspci` I can at least find my ethernet, USB, ... controllers, but nothing stating wireless, WLAN, or similar. I can neither install additional drivers over Software & Updates as none get displayed, even when mounting a fresh iso and trying to take the drivers from there.

Using `sudo lshw -class network` gets me:

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.2
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
   logical name: enp4s0f2
   version: 0a
   serial: 00:90:f5:e7:5b:07
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-37-generic firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 62:82:59:0e:0b:56
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host 
driverversion=5.13.0-37-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.194.172 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

I also tried Ubuntu 20.04 from a Live USB, but no wifi or bluetooth adapters were found there either. Ubuntu is the only system installed.

My guess now is that the hardware somehow broke, it is an older laptop. Is there any way to fix this, is it something different? I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

EDIT:

`lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:301d Dell Computer Corp. Dell Universal Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2717:ff80 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Does `lsusb` return anything related to your network device? Not all network adapters use the PCI bus 

Comment: Sorry, the comment is totally unfomatted. Basically, it returns nothind I would interpret as a wifi card or similar, besides my phone I use to tether the wifi with to my computer. I edited my post instead.

Comment: Is your Bluetooth and/or WiFi activated in BIOS and switched on with buttons?

Comment: So I tried searching it under the options I have: Main/Advanced/Securtiy/Boot/Exit. The closes coming to something wifi related was under Boot -> Network Device BBS Priorities where I can under Boot Options #1 choose Realtek PXE B04 DOO or Disabled. It is on enabled. I also tried resetting all options, the problem persists.

Comment: What laptop are you using? Do you know what your network devices are? Depending on which hardware you are using can make a big difference as to the ease of the solution. I have had similar things happen where the easiest solution was to tether through my phone and search for appropriate drivers eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: When asking for help with hardware problems please include information related to the hardware you are using - try searching the products specifications and including them with your answer as some hardware combinations have particular bugs/issues.